# Histograma de imagem em PHP

Tags: php

Olá, tenho uma dúvida:

Como faria um histograma de uma imagem em PHP, que eu determinasse qual a coordenada da imagem a ser analisada e me retornasse somente duas coisas, quantidade de tons claros e quantidade de tons escuros.

Alguma ideia de como poderia fazer isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Pergunta interessante. Você não tem nenhum código? Ou alguma biblioteca em mente?

Comment: Olá amigo! Não tenho nenhum código, mas pensei em usar a biblioteca Imagick, o que acha? Alguma sugestão de biblioteca diferente?

Comment: Então, eu olhei a GD do php. Vou realizar alguns testes e ver se consigo te ajudar de alguma forma.

Comment: Oh campeão, muito obrigado! Vai me dar um mega "help"!

Comment: Bom, tem essa [API aqui](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color-summarizer/?api)
veja [esse exemplo](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color-summarizer/?url=http://www.tocadigital.com.br/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/toca_digital.png&precision=PRECISION).

Comment: E em PHP, tem [esse aqui](http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract).

Answer (score 1):

Bom, para fazer essa resposta, além de testes, tive que realizar algumas pesquisas que vou mostrar no discorrer do tema. Usei a biblioteca GD, não por ser a melhor, mas foi a primeira que encontrei e consegui realizar os testes.

A primeira pergunta que me veio a mente foi:
**Como distinguir um tom claro de um tom escuro de forma matemática?**

Usei essa paleta abaixo para perguntar para os meus participantes quais tons eram claros, médios ou escuros na opinião deles. Todos tiveram respostas diferentes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois eu separei apenas duas cores dessa paleta, e perguntei qual das duas tinha tom mais claro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos acharam que o roxo era mais claro. Isso acontece porque o roxo é uma cor fria e o amarelo é uma cor quente. Porém quando as imagens foram transformadas em grayscale ficou mais evidente que o roxo era a cor mais escura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém as duas na opinião geral são cores claras. *Qual a finalidade dessa análise até aqui?* É importante ressaltar que é uma opinião ou é necessário uma comparação ou criar um padrão para rotular uma cor de "clara / escura / média" em determinadas situações pois a matemática trabalha com exatas, e o que eu quero é chegar o mais próximo de uma solução viável para o seu problema. É importante colocar que o que queremos aqui é descobrir os tons claros dos escuros, sem analisar saturação, brilho, luminosidade, etc.

Pensado nisso cheguei nessa solução:

1. Padronizar valores dos tons claros e escuros.
2. Transformar a imagem em grayscale.
3. Analisar parte da imagem com as coordenadas selecionadas.
4. Retornar quantidade de pixels com tons escuros, claros e médios conforme o padrão criado.

Abaixo temos o formulário para enviar a imagem e as coordenadas a serem analisadas.

```
<form style="width: 300px;" action="analisarImagem.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    
    <input type="file" name="imagem"/>
    
    <p style="width: 100%;">Coordernada X</p>
    <input style="width: 150px; float: left;" type="text" name="x1" placeholder="Inicio"/>
    <input style="width: 150px; float: left;" type="text" name="x2" placeholder="Fim"/>
    
    <p style="width: 100%;">Coordernada Y</p>
    <input style="width: 150px; float: left;" type="text" name="y1" placeholder="Inicio"/>
    <input style="width: 150px; float: left;" type="text" name="y2" placeholder="Fim"/>

    <input type="submit" name="analisar" value="Analisar"/>
    
</form>
```

E o código comentado que faz a analise:
**analisarImagem.php**

A função do php `imagecolorat()` retorna o valor da cor do pixel selecionado.
**16777215** é o valor máximo que representa a cor 100% em branco e **0** é o valor mínimo que representa uma cor 100% em preto.

Com isso eu padronizei a nomenclatura com os valores que são retornados.

```
<?php 
    
    
    /*
        
        padrão da nomenclatura:
        tom claro = acima de 8388607
        tom escuro = abaixo de 8388608
    
    */
    
    // quantidade de tons na area selecionada que inicia do 0.
    $tonsClaros = 0;
    $tonsEscuros = 0;
    
    // cria uma nova imagem a partir da imagem enviada
    $imagem = $_FILES['imagem'];
    move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'], "imagem/".$imagem['name']);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("imagem/".$imagem['name']);
    
    // Aqui eu transformo a imagem em grayscale
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    
    // Obter largura e altura da imagem selecionada
    $inicioX = (int)$_POST['x1'];
    $finalX = (int)$_POST['x2'];
    
    $inicioY = (int)$_POST['y1'];
    $finalY = (int)$_POST['y2'];

    // analisar cada pixel de parte da imagem selecionada

    for ($y = $inicioY; $y < $finalY; $y++) {
        
        for ($x = $inicioX; $x < $finalX; $x++) {

            // Obter a cor do pixel da posicao [$x, $y]
            $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
            
            if($rgb > 8388607){
                
                $tonsClaros++;
                
            } else {
                
                $tonsEscuros++;
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    echo "Quantidade de Tons Claros -> ".$tonsClaros."</br>";
    echo "Quantidade de Tons Escuros -> ".$tonsEscuros."</br>";
    
    
?>
```

**Exemplo 1:**

Essa imagem do Homer ela claramente é uma imagem com tons mais claros com largura de 400px e altura de 408px. Quando enviei essa imagem selecionei o valor máximo da largura e da altura e o valor retornado foi:

> Quantidade de Tons Claros -> 137528
>
> Quantidade de Tons Escuros -> 25672

*Obs.: Se você somar esses 2 valores você terá a quantidade total da área em pixels. Ou seja, 400x408. Isso significa que todos os pixels foram analisados.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo 2:**

Na mesma imagem eu selecionei apenas a parte que contem o revólver.

**Coordenada x: 200 - 260 e Coordenada Y: 77 - 165**

Resultado:

> Quantidade de Tons Claros -> 0
>
> Quantidade de Tons Escuros -> 5280

Com isso, você pode implementar vários tipos de estatísticas e histogramas.

*Fontes:*

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecolorat.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagefilter.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.image.php